# Notations for finite field of $p$ elements with $p$ prime

Tags: ring-theory, notation, finite-fields

Assuming $p$ is a prime, there are many notations that I would recognize (without need to define them explicitly) for the finite field of $p$ elements, also known as Galois field of $p$ elements, also the ring of integers modulo $p$.

| Id | Notation | LaTeX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | $GF(p)$ | `GF(p)` |
| 1b | $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ | `\operatorname{GF}(p)` |
| 2a | $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ | `\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z` |
| 2b | $Z/pZ$ | `Z/pZ` |
| 3a | $\mathbb Z_p$ | `\mathbb Z_p` |
| 3b | $(\mathbb Z_p,+,\times)$ | `(\mathbb Z_p,+,\times)` |
| 3c | $(\mathbb Z_p,+,\cdot)$ | `(\mathbb Z_p,+,\cdot)` |
| 3d | $(\mathbb Z_p,+,*)$ | `(\mathbb Z_p,+,*)` |
| 4a | $\mathbb F_p$ | `\mathbb F_p` |
| 4b | $(\mathbb F_p,+,\times)$ | `(\mathbb F_p,+,\times)` |
| 4c | $(\mathbb F_p,+,\cdot)$ | `(\mathbb F_p,+,\cdot)` |
| 4d | $(\mathbb F_p,+,*)$ | `(\mathbb F_p,+,*)` |

Which are most recommendable / canonical / common, and which are best avoided, perhaps with indication of branch of mathematics or educational level? Is there some recommendable other that I missed?

If we had to choose one of 4b/4c/4d because we want to state a notation for the multiplication, which would it be?

[if questions on notation are not acceptable, please tell in comment where that's stated and I'll happily close the question]

Comment: All of them as far as you clearly define notations at the beginning. You can even use others notations like $\mathcal G^{\mathbb F\mathscr P}_{\star}$ or $\cap\cup$ if you wish... In mathematic your are free with notations as far as you defined them clearly in the introduction. I personally use $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_p$, but this is just a habit.

Comment: I wouldn't use  $\Bbb Z_p$ because that's used for the p-adics

Comment: @Lukas Heger: would that ambiguity with the p-adics be fully solved by using 3b/3c/3d e.g. $(\mathbb Z_p,+,\times)$, or would we still need to use something else if we wanted to explicit the notation for multiplication, perhaps $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,+,\times)$ or $(\mathbb F_p,+,\times)$?

Comment: The use of * to denote multiplication is a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics, so avoid 3d unless you're actually writing code.

Comment: 1a is only used by people who don't understand / don't care for typography. What they mean is 1b.

Comment: @fgrieu No, because the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a ring so also carries its addition and multiplication with the same notation as any other rings.  Do not use $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the prime field of characteristic $p$ unless you want to confuse people.

Comment: @fgrieu the p-adics have addition and multiplication as well, so I don't see 3b/3c/3d resolving any ambiguity

Comment: Another vote against 3d and 4d here. In formal mathematics, the $\ast$ symbol is almost never used for multiplication. If you use it that way, some readers will be confused and some will be scornful.

Comment: 1b, 2a, 4a seem to be the podium in the set category, with 4b standing strong in the triple category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best accepted are:

$\operatorname{GF}(p)$

$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$

$\mathbb F_p$

$(\mathbb F_p,+,\times)$ if we want to define the multiplication operator.